# Reset Angular back to default

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

Sorry, I think my question wording is a little vague.

I've been trying to work through some Angular 2+ tutorials. At first everything was fine, then I decided to have a go at Angular-Material and/or Bootstrap 4 (which required updating to Angular 6). Upon attempting to get this stuff going, I ended up coming into problems where each successive step I took to fix things just made it all worse.

I'm now running into all kinds of errors, and can't even get a stock Angular project on Visual Studio (2017) to run. The errors started with things like 'Module Parse Error' and have now reached the stage where some parts of Angular don't even know they exist any more. I can't even use `ng new Project` to create a barebones project from the command line any more because `Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...Ze433ne....'`

Honestly at this point I don't even care about working through error messages and/or finding a solution. I just want to reset the whole thing back to normal, as it was two days ago before I started all this.

For the sake of completeness, I guess I'll add that I've tried things like `ng update -all` and `npm cache verify`, and (what I believe is the main problem) I deleted a few folders from the npm-cache folder of AppData on my computer, as recommended by another response on here. I guess it would be good to undelete those folders, but if I attempt to restore them the process always stalls halfway through, so they're oddly stuck in the recycle bin.

As you can see, it's become a bit of a mess, hence the desire to just restart it all.

Any pointers on getting Angular back to default would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You could always take the all-out approach and uninstall / reinstall node and npm

Comment: @user184994 Thanks, this did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being what @user184994 suggest in a comment after my question:

> "You could always take the all-out approach and uninstall / reinstall node and npm"

I did this, then to get Angular 6 working properly I found I needed to tell Visual Studio where to look specifically for the latest Node install (otherwise it was still finding an old version, even though I installed it).

For those who may be stuck doing this, the answer lies in:

VS2017 -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management -> External Web Tools

then manually add the location where the most up-to-date nodejs install lives. For me it was `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

and finally, **put the location at the top of the list**, by using the up/down arrows next to the Add New button (all nested at the top-right of the view area). This tells Visual Studio to look there first.

Now everything is gravy, Angular 6 is working, the new Bootstrap is working, all is right with the world once more.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Angular CLI as a global package, clean npm cache and install it again:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

This should fix the global installed Angular CLI. For any specific project you can try to remove the node_nodules folder and install all the dependencies again.